# Impossible to update table php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple way to update a table for a class work, but it doesn't work at all. I looked my code a lot of time, but I can't find what's the error.

Bellow are the steps for my code :

1. session start
2. I have a form with login username and password
3. Values
4. PHP server login
5. Verify user (I found this code on the web, so maybe there is an easier way)
6. After that I have an IF user exist, show another form where you can edit this user informations.
   But it seem that my update table doesn't work.

   $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET nom=$Nom, login=$login, motdepasse=$MotDePasse, niveauacces=$NiveauAcces WHERE login=$login";

   $result=mysql_query($sql);
7. If the user doesn't exist, get an error.

The thing is that my table is not updating when clicking to update table and it go dirrectly to the error (else).

Bellow is my table to import into wamp phpMyAdmin.

http://gavitex.com/share/85tn5rigs

DataBase name : usagers

Table name : TableUsagers (it will be auto)

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ob_start( );
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Exercice 2</title>

 </head>
 <body>
 <?php

 if (empty($_POST["login"])||empty($_POST["motdepasse"])) {

 ?>

    <form action="#" method="post">
    <!--Nom : <input name="nom"><br>-->
    Utilisateur : <input name="login"><br>
    Mot de passe : <input name="motdepasse"><br>
    <!--niveau d'accès : <select name="niveauacces">
                        <option value="1">Invité</option>
                        <option value="2">Usager</option>
                        <option value="3">Administrateur</option>
                    </select><br>-->
    <input type="submit" name="Entrer" value="Entrer">
    </form>

  <?php

  }else{

  $host="localhost"; // Host name 
  $username="root"; // Mysql username 
  $password=""; // Mysql password 
  $db_name="usagers"; // Database name 
  $tbl_name="tableusagers"; // Table name

  // Get values from form 
  $login=$_POST['login'];
  $MotDePasse=$_POST['motdepasse'];


  // Connect to server and select database.
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  /* Verify if user exist */
  $requete = "select login, motdepasse from $tbl_name where login='$login' AND motdepasse ='$MotDePasse'";
  $verif = mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_verif = mysql_fetch_assoc($verif);
  $user = mysql_num_rows($verif);



  if($user){
      echo "Modifier des informations :<br>
      <form action='#' method='post'>
      Nom : <input name='nom'><br>
      Utilisateur : <input name='login'><br>
      Mot de passe : <input name='motdepasse'><br>
      niveau d'accès : <select name='niveauacces'>
                        <option value='1'>Invité</option>
                        <option value='2'>Usager</option>
                        <option value='3'>Administrateur</option>
                    </select><br>
          <input type='submit' name='modifier' value='Modifier'>
          </form>";

        /* Values */        
        if(isset($_POST['modifier'])){
        $Nom=$_POST['nom'];
        $NiveauAcces=$_POST['niveauacces'];
        $login=$_POST['login'];
        $MotDePasse=$_POST['motdepasse'];

        // Update data into mysql 
        $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET nom=$Nom, login=$login, motdepasse=$MotDePasse, niveauacces=$NiveauAcces WHERE login=$login";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        }


  }else{
      echo "error";
  }

  mysql_close();

  }
  ?> 


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: checking for errors will pay off, *"ten fold"*

Comment: Write down your code here. So people able to analyze your code directly and giving help without have to go to another link.

Comment: I added the full code

Comment: This whole line `$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET nom=$Nom, login=$login, motdepasse=$MotDePasse, niveauacces=$NiveauAcces WHERE login=$login";` is failing you. Again, use proper error checking as this `echo "error";` doesn't help you.

Comment: How can I use a proper error checking? The echo error is just if the user doesn't exist. Maybe I should make something else. Also, what's wrong with my whole line?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Sir @Fred-ii- do you able to give personal internet training so i can improving my skill & knowledge on programming? Looking for tutor since long time ago :D

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Flattering, but no I don't. I am *thee worse* to teach. Believe me, I tried and teacher blood just wasn't handed down in my DNA ;-)

Comment: @Nucleo1985 You could go over some of my answers though and their related questions too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haaa, i knew this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update is not working because you are not properly binding the variables to your query. Use (`'`) when binding a string to your query. Not using (`'`) for your variables are only valid when the value of the variable is an integer.

```
$sql = "UPDATE ".$tbl_name."
            SET nom='$Nom',
                login='$login',
                motdepasse='$MotDePasse',
                niveauacces='$NiveauAcces'
            WHERE login='$login'";
```

And before you bind variables to your query, make sure to sanitize the value using at least [`*_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$Nom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nom']);
$NiveauAcces = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['niveauacces']);
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$MotDePasse = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['motdepasse']);
```

### Problem:

After submitting your edit form, it will not go to the `if(isset($_POST['modifier']))` condition because it is inside of an else condition `else {}` of the the very first condition `if(isset($_POST["login"]) ...)`.

And `mysql_*` is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), so we recommend that you use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

### Recommendations:

What I would recommend is to separate your file into..hmm..at least six (6) files.

Lets go first for the header (header.php) and footer (footer.php) respectively:

**header.php** (*so when you have to change the header, you don't have to edit each file*):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start( );
    include("conn.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Exercice 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

**footer.php**:

```
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your login page (**login.php**):

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_SESSION["login"])){ /* IF USER IS ALREADY LOGGED IN */
        header("edit.php"); /* REDIRECT TO HOME PAGE */
    }

    include("header.php");

?>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
    Utilisateur : <input type="text" name="login"><br>
    Mot de passe : <input type="password" name="motdepasse"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Entrer" value="Entrer">
</form>

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

And your edit page (**edit.php**):

```
include("header.php");

echo 'Modifier des informations :<br>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        Nom : <input name="nom"><br>
        Utilisateur : <input type="text" name="login"><br>
        Mot de passe : <input type="password" name="motdepasse"><br>
        niveau d\'accès : <select name="niveauacces">
                             <option value="1">Invité</option>
                             <option value="2">Usager</option>
                             <option value="3">Administrateur</option>
                         </select><br>
        <input type="submit" name="modifier" value="Modifier">
    </form>';

include("footer.php");
```

Then lets establish your connection to the database (**conn.php**):

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "usagers");

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then lets have a page where you process all submitted forms (**process.php**):

```
session_start();
include("conn.php");

if(isset($_POST["Entrer"])){ /* PROCESS LOGIN FORM */

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT login, motdepasse FROM tableusagers WHERE login = ? AND motdepasse = ?"); /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["login"], $_POST["motdepasse"]); /* BIND THESE TWO VARIABLES TO YOUR QUERY; s STANDS FOR STRING */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE PREPARED QUERY */
    $stmt->store_result(); /* FOR THE PURPOSE OF GETTING THE NUMBER OF RESULTS */
    if($stmt->num_rows > 1){ /* CHECK IF ROW RESULTS IS MORE THAN ONE */
        $_SESSION["login"] = $_POST["login"]; /* STORE LOGIN DATA TO A SESSION VARIABLE */
        header("LOCATION:edit.php"); /* REDIRECT TO HOME OR EDIT PAGE */
    } else {
        header("LOCATION:login.php"); /* REDIRECT BACK TO LOGIN PAGE */
    }
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE PREPARED STATEMENT */

}

else if(isset($_POST["modifier"])){ /* PROCESS EDIT FORM */

    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tableusagers SET login = ?, motdepasse = ?, niveauacces = ? WHERE login = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssis", $_POST["login"], $_POST["motdepasse"], $_POST["niveauacces"]), $_SESSION["login"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    header("LOCATION:edit.php"); /* REDIRECT BACK TO EDIT PAGE */
}

else {
    header("LOCATION:login.php");
}
```

Try storing hashed passwords in your database for additional security. Check php's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

This approach is a bit extreme programming but I think it would still work. So I suggest you read more about Object Oriented Programming (OOP) or try out different libraries that will do it for you (*CodeIgniter, Laravel, etc.*).

Comment: I suspect that the sanitisation step is redundant when using prepared statements- but may be

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, but I suggested the `*_real_escape_string` if OP would insist on using `mysql_*`, but I did not use it anymore on my `prepared statement` answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this line is not proper:

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET nom=$Nom, login=$login, motdepasse=$MotDePasse, niveauacces=$NiveauAcces WHERE login=$login"
```

try this:

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET nom='$Nom', motdepasse='$MotDePasse', niveauacces='$NiveauAcces' WHERE login='$login';"
```

I have omitted `elogin=$login,` which is already use in where clause.

Comment: I have only suggested the logic, as per  script....it should be consider the sql injection also.